# How to disable long press on keys in custom keyboard android?

Tags: android, android-softkeyboard, custom-keyboard

I want to disable long press on keys on my custom keyboard.for implementing customkeyboard i extended View class.like below but there is no method to handle longpress

```
 public class CustomKeyboard extends View {
     @Override
            public void onPress(int arg0) {
                Log.d("Gajanand", "onPress:GK ");

            }

            @Override
            public void onRelease(int primaryCode) {
                Log.d("Gajanand", "onRelease: GK");
            }

            @Override
            public void onText(CharSequence text) {
            }

            @Override
            public void swipeDown() {
            }

            @Override
            public void swipeLeft() {
            }

            @Override
            public void swipeRight() {
            }

            @Override
            public void swipeUp() {
            }
}
```

help me to handle on long press. i want to disable long press completely.

Comment: After click you can disable the button untill another button is not pressed

Comment: @jakirhussain yes but here no buttons all are keys custom keys unable to handle onlong press

Comment: just do this @Override
public void onRelease(int primaryCode) {  
    myPopupWindow.dismiss();
}

Answer (score 0):

You can use `PopupWindow` class and populate it with custom layout.

```
PopupWindow popup = new PopupWindow(context);
popup.setContentView(custom);
```

On click in the popup you can dismiss it.

```
 @Override
 public void onRelease(int primaryCode) {
 Log.d("Gajanand", "onRelease: GK");
 popup.dismiss();
 }
```

Happy coding!!

Comment: when user will long press, it will be disable by above code. whatever your keyboard is open or not. just try this.
i already implement custom keyboard.

Comment: is it possible to disable keyboard completely on press of some key and enable on release?